# ASP.NET Identity валидация пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Создал класс для валидации пользователя.Метод ValidateAsync возвращает, что ошибок нет (Errors.Count() = 0), однако св-во Succeded также равен false.Как и при каких обстоятельствах он задается как true?

Код валидатора:

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserValidator<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager;

    public CustomUserValidator(ApplicationUserManager userManager) : base(userManager)
    {
       this.UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        //var result = await base.ValidateAsync(user);
        var result = new IdentityResult();

        if (user.UserName != null && (await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName) != null))
        {
            List<string> errors = result.Errors.ToList();
            errors.Add($"Адрес {user.UserName} уже используется.");
            result = new IdentityResult(errors);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

В ApplicationUserManager(реализация UserManager) в качестве валидатора задан экземпляр этого класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается надо самому возвращать Success в случае, если ошибок нет.
Следующий код решает эту проблему.

```
     if (result.Errors.Count() == 0)
     return IdentityResult.Success;
     else return result;
```